# How to call server side data for next page before navigation?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, preload

After studying documentation, I am familiar that redux creates a global store and for better SEO performance SSR (Server side rendering) is a good choice where I preload my data in first landing page and then I can dispatch it directly in my global store to render DOM in html page for SEO optimization.

Something like `window.__PRELOAD_STATE__` is used.

However, I have a question in my mind. there is a scenario like in my first page, I have preloaded my data in json. Now after click the link somewhere I want to navigate to another page. How can I again preload the next page of data without refreshing page? I understood that I have to call the Server side data but how?

Is it possible?

**HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATED!!!**